# Error when we modify the storagePath of the service artifact in WSO2 Registry

Tags: wso2

We want to change the storage path of the services in the WSO2 Registry.

We would like to add a subdirectoy in the path with the name of obligatory field of our service artifact

In the service artifact template exits the storagePath node and we have introduced this

```
<storagePath>/trunk/services/@{overview_rutaMapaFuncional}/@{namespace}/@{name}</storagePath>
```

where overview_rutaMapaFuncional is defined in our service artifact

The modified artifact is saved correctly  but when we try to save a service we receive this error:

Failed to add the artifact, Special characters are not allowed in the name fields

In the log we can see:

[2013-06-05 19:25:10,915] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.GovernanceArtifactManager} -  Failed to add artifact: artifact id: 4f9fcf77-fba
b-481c-b2f4-d8d7ffd0cbf3, path: /trunk/services/com/prueba/prueba/Prueba. Resource does not exist at path /_system/governance/trunk/services/RutaPrueb
a/com/prueba/prueba
org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundException: Resource does not exist at path /_system/governance/trunk/services/RutaPrueba/com/
prueba/prueba
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.get(EmbeddedRegistry.java:532)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.extensions.handlers.ServiceMediaTypeHandler.put(ServiceMediaTypeHandler.java:361)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerManager.put(HandlerManager.java:2503)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerLifecycleManager.put(HandlerLifecycleManager.java:1007)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.put(EmbeddedRegistry.java:697)
....

We want to change the storage path of the services in the WSO2 Registry.

We would like to add a subdirectory in the path with the name of an obligatory field of our service artifact

We have modified the storagePath node of the service artifact template. We have introduced this:

```
<storagePath>/trunk/services/@{overview_rutaMapaFuncional}/@{namespace}/@{name}</storagePath>
```

where overviewrutaMapaFuncional is defined in our service artifact

(we have also tested other possibilites but we think that this possibility is the most close to the correct one)

The modified artifact is saved correctly but when we try to save a service we receive this error:

Failed to add the artifact, Special characters are not allowed in the name fields

In the log we can see:

[2013-06-05 20:27:58,477] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.GovernanceArtifactManager} -  Failed to add artifact: artifact id: 57784646-f2c
3-4459-8cfc-8c6e28557987, path: /trunk/services/com/text/www/Name. Resource does not exist at path /_system/governance/trunk/services/Ruta/com/test/www
org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundException: Resource does not exist at path /_system/governance/trunk/services/Ruta/com/test/www
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.get(EmbeddedRegistry.java:532)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.extensions.handlers.ServiceMediaTypeHandler.put(ServiceMediaTypeHandler.java:361)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerManager.put(HandlerManager.java:2503)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerLifecycleManager.put(HandlerLifecycleManager.java:1007)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.put(EmbeddedRegistry.java:697)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.put(CacheBackedRegistry.java:465)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.put(UserRegistry.java:658)
        at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.GovernanceArtifactManager.addGovernanceArtifact(GovernanceArtifactManager.java:155)

What are we doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug the service is not saved because path creation is not done correctly. This will be looked at and fixed in the future releases. Thank you for pointing this out.